# How to retrieve an entry input from one class and use it from another class? (python 3.7.1)

Tags: python-3.x, class, tkinter

I've been trying to find a solution to this problem, but I seem to be stuck in a corner. I'm trying to get an entry input from the user (their first name) from one class, and input that entry into a label for another class, so that I could create a text based game. Here's a simplification of what my code looks like right now:

```
from tkinter import *

class Page6(Tk):
  def Page6():
    window=Toplevel()
    window.geometry("1920x1080")
    window["bg"] = ("#FFB6C1")
    window.title("Dating Simulator")

    iag = PhotoImage(file="Images\ClassroomTextBoxThree.gif")
    labelfour = Label(window, image=iag)
    labelfour.place(x=-100,y=-50)
    labelfour.photo = iag

    textThree = Label(window, text ="Hello What is your Name?", font= "Times 15")
    textThree.place( x = 80, y = 60)

    #add name to code/username below
    #the code below is where I want to retrieve the input from class Page2

    MyButton1 = Button(window, text="Hello my name is" +  E1.get(), width=10, font="Times 20", command=Page7.Page7)
    MyButton1.place(x=1120, y=275)

class Page2(Tk):
  def Page2():
    window=Toplevel()
    window.geometry("1920x1080")
    window["bg"] = ("#FFB6C1")
    window.title("Dating Simulator")

    imag = PhotoImage(file="Images\Minami.gif")
    labelthree = Label(window, image=imag)
    labelthree.place(x=-100,y=-50)
    labelthree.photo = imag
    #labelthree.pack(side="right")

    #E1 is where the user should input their name 

    E1 = Entry(window, bd = 5)
    E1.place(x=1100, y= 675)

    EntryOne = Label(window, text = "Please insert your name (First name only):", font = "Times 20", bg ="#ffffff")
    EntryOne.place(x=600,y=200)

    MyButton1 = Button(window, text="Submit", width=10, font="Times 20", command=Page3.Page3)
    MyButton1.place(x=1090, y=725)
```

I tried looking up other solutions from other posts, but either only involved taking data from one class or just a variable, not a entry input. The working product should make the button (from class Page6) include the user's name input from class Page2 as a part of its text. Thank you very much for reading.

Comment: Will a static variable work?

Comment: Anything will work for now. Thank you!